# The blessing over drinking fresh orange juice

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

Before someone drinks a fresh orange juice, which of the following blessings is required to be said? Should the blessing be "shehakol"? "borai pri ha'etz"? or both?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the Brachot site](http://www.berachot.org/Q+A/index.html#31)

> Q31) What bracha would one make on orange juice with the pulp bits
>   inside?
>
> A31) Fruit juices generally lose their ha'eitz bracha and become
>   shehakol. Although there has been some discussion why that is so even
>   in cases where the fruits are planted for the sake of the juice (which
>   is how juices are made today) - nevertheless the prevalent minhag
>   ha'olam is to still make shehakol on these fruit juices. As far as the
>   pulp is concerned, it is tafel, or subordinate - because if you wanted
>   the actual fruit then you should just eat the actual fruit..

Comment: The minority opinion -- ha'etz because those oranges were grown for their juice -- is the Chazon Ish, by the way.

Comment: The user specified a "fresh" orange juice suggesting they squeezed it themselves, in which case the orange was probably one grown for eating not squeezing.

Comment: @CashCow I inferred that. also, though the definition of "fresh" is ambiguous. Regardless, I think the rules would be the same. What may require research, though, is what happens with oranges grown in the U.S. AFAIK, only certain types of oranges are usable as juice. (They sell them in the store as "juice" oranges. Navel oranges, IIRC, don't make great juice. Admittedly, the above answer may be too "general" and might not be considering this aspect.