# Blessing on orange juice after eating an orange

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

Say someone ate an orange and now wants to drink orange juice. The regular blessing on orange juice is *sheakol* (see e.g., [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65111/the-blessing-over-drinking-fresh-orange-juice)) although there is some opinion it might be *haeitz* if the oranges were grown for juice.

Does the blessing change if one has already said *borei peri haeitz* on the orange that was eaten?

On one side these are different blessings, on the other side maybe the blessing on orange juice is *haeitz* and is no more required. Do things change if one had the intention to drink the juice when saying the blessing over the orange? Or (as suggested by Danny Schoemann) if the juice was in front of one or in the same room when making the blessing on the orange?